# Peculiar way of getting a number for comparison

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was looking at the codebase today, and I found something strange. In one file, which is used very, very often and it is critical. Critical in terms it is a submodule for large project, so many almost all microservices use it. I found this:

```
if(/*removed for brevity*/&& this._someArray.length > [''].length) {
//... code continues
}
```

Intention here is obvious. I understand the good part to remove a magic number 1 from the code, but AFAIK this method of getting a number **1** has some time penalties.

Now, is there something else here at play, which I am not familiar with, or this is just a bad style/practice?

Comment: This is definitely weird... Seeing that, I'd think just like you and replace it by a variable valued to 1, or better, by nothing. Did you check the history on the file? Maybe it is like that because of half a refactoring?

Comment: I think it is better define a constant

Comment: Since `[''].length` always evaluates to `1`, hardcoding it to `1` should be fine, I guess?

Comment: That is my guess as well. But since I always learn something new, I certainly hope this is a guru move. And I want to know why.

Comment: Chances are it's a wtf. https://thedailywtf.com/series/code-sod